# inner class members put into outer class pointer array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class k {

public:
    class test {
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        test(int a) { x = a; }
        void print() { cout << x << endl; }
    };
    void output();
    vector<test> vect;
};

void k::output()
{
    vect.push_back(test(1));
    vect.push_back(test(2));
    vect.push_back(test(3));
    vect.push_back(test(-56));

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        vect[j].print();
}

int main()
{
    k m;
    m.output();

    return 0;
}
```

I have nested loop include outer class k and inner class test.I am using vector ,writing inner class datas as outer class member.Then I am trying write this data into outer class pointer array as test * arr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class k {

public:
    class test {
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        test(int a) { x = a; }
        void print() { cout << x << endl; }
    };
    void output();
    test* arr;
};

void k::output()
{

    arr[0] = test(5);

    arr[0].print();
}

int main()
{
    k m;
    m.output();

    return 0;
}
```

I am tyring to put this datas in vector I get an error.How can I put this data that in inner class in outer class pointer array ?How can avoid from dangling?

Comment: `test *arr; [...] arr[0] = test(5);`. This is UB. `arr` is a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Why do you want to drop `std::vector` (working solution)? If you are not allowed to use std stuff, write your awn simplified vector class.

Comment: Concerning terminology: formally, C++ has **nested** classes. "Inner" and "outer" are a Java thing, and bring with them several assumptions that don't apply in C++. It's better to stay away from those two.